# How to add html tables in progress 4gl?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I created a temp table in Progress4gl and I need to email the data from temp table using html syntax. Which means I need to link all the fields in temp table to html table and email.

The fields in temp table are:

> Part_ID, CustomerPartID, customer

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could just output the HTML.  Something like this:

```
define temp-table tt_test
  field f1 as integer
  field f2 as character
  field f3 as date
.

create tt_test.
assign
  f1 = 1
  f2 = "abc"
  f3 = today
.
create tt_test.
assign
  f1 = 2
  f2 = "xyz"
  f3 = today + 30
.

output to value( "mytable.html" ).

put unformatted "<table>" skip.

for each tt_test:

  put unformatted substitute( "  <tr><td>&1</td><td>&2</td><td>&3</td></tr>", f1, f2, f3 ) skip.

end.

put unformatted "</table>" skip.

output close.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom. I was finally able to create an html file out of it. However, I made some minor changes by adding styles to it.

Now I would require this html file to be added to an email body. Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: When putting character data into HTML, it must be escaped. Not doing so will break the table.

Comment: In a comment to another answer you mentioned sendEmail.p.  SFAIK that is not a standard Progress provided procedure and I have no familiarity with its operation.  I assume that it accepts an argument for the body of the email and that you would pass your formatted table via that argument.  OTOH, if "sendEmail.p" was an aspirational comment and you were hoping someone might provide such a program my suggestion is that you ask a new question focused on how to write a program to send emails using Progress 4gl.  It will be helpful to know what platform you are on and what email provider you use.

Comment: Also, while my answer is "quick and dirty" and the code is pretty easy to follow Stefan's answer is actually much more complete and robust.

Answer (score 1):

For creating an html table you can (ab)use the power of datasets combined with serialize-name:

```
/* Write some awesome ABL code here, or load an existing snippet! */ 

define temp-table ttparts serialize-name "tr"
   field part_id        as char serialize-name "td"
   field customerPartID as char serialize-name "td"
   field customer       as char serialize-name "td"
   .

define dataset ds serialize-name "table" for ttparts .

define buffer bupart for ttparts.

create bupart.
assign
   bupart.part_id = "one"
   bupart.customer = "A"
   .

create bupart.
assign
   bupart.part_id = "two"
   bupart.customer = "B"
   .

def var lcc as longchar no-undo.
dataset ds:write-xml( "longchar", lcc, true ).

message string( lcc ).
```

https://abldojo.services.progress.com:443/#/?shareId=5d1618c14b1a0f40c34b8bc8

An updated version which accepts any temp-table handle and will return a longchar containing the HTML table:

```
function createHtmlTable returns longchar (
  i_ht as handle
):

   def var lcc as longchar.
   def var hds as handle.
   def var hb  as handle.
   def var ic  as int.

   create dataset hds.
   hds:serialize-name = "table". // not needed if stripped below

   create buffer hb for table i_ht.
   hb:serialize-name = "tr".
   hds:add-buffer( hb ).

   do ic = 1 to hb:num-fields:
      hb:buffer-field( ic ):serialize-name = "td".
   end.

   hds:write-xml( "longchar", lcc, true ).

   // remove xml declaration
   lcc = substring( lcc, index( lcc, "<", 2 ) ).   
   entry( 1, lcc, ">" ) = "<table". // see comment above

   return lcc.

   finally:
      delete object hds.
   end finally.

end function.

define temp-table ttparts
   field part_id as char
   field customerPartID as char
   field customer as char
   .

define buffer bupart for ttparts.

create bupart.
assign
   bupart.part_id = "one"
   bupart.customer = "A"
   .

create bupart.
assign
   bupart.part_id = "two"
   bupart.customer = "B"
   .

message string( createHtmlTable( temp-table ttparts:handle ) ).
```

https://abldojo.services.progress.com/#/?shareId=5d1760d84b1a0f40c34b8bcd

Comment: That is ... um, I am at a loss for words.  It's clever.  But I'm pretty sure I would have to fire any programmer who actually tried to put that into production.

Comment: Once you get over the initial shock, it's quite alright once you consider that a temp-table is a table, a record is a row and a field is a cell, so (serialize-)name them as such. I would happily put this into production (minus the true for formatting the xml output obviously ;-)).

Comment: I have to admit that it is tempting.  But trick coding is a maintenance nightmare and a bug waiting to happen.  The "<?xml version="1.0"?> <table xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">" stuff kind of ruins it too.

Comment: There is nothing 'trick coding' about using serialize-name, it is a one way mapping - if you do not want the xml declaration it can easily be removed (I would). As a bonus, by using proven existing methods - instead of cobbling your own - I do not need to think about escaping my data. 
What's that you say? 
You do not have a customer part called </table>? 
Ah, alright then, you'll be fine ;-)

Comment: The “trick” part is that WRITE-XML isn’t exactly an obvious and self documenting approach to obtaining an HTML table.  Excellent point about escaping data.  I would at least encapsulate the trick inside a well named, and thoroughly commented function.  With a bit of cleverness it might even be possible to manipulate the SERIALIZE-NAME inside that function.

Comment: Agreed. https://abldojo.services.progress.com:443/#/?shareId=5d1760d84b1a0f40c34b8bcd
Will take any temp-table (handle) and spit it out as an html table.

Comment: Nice!  (Apparently there is a minimum comment length)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in method to do this. One way that I could think of is converting the temp table to json and then json to HTML. I believe there are several utilities to convert json to html table. You can convert temp table to json in ABL using WRITE-JSON method.

An example from Progress documentation:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cTargetType AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFile       AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lFormatted  AS LOGICAL   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lRetOK      AS LOGICAL   NO-UNDO.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttCust NO-UNDO LIKE Customer.

/* Code to populate the temp-table */  
ASSIGN  
  cTargetType = "file" 
  cFile       = "ttCust.json" 
  lFormatted  = TRUE. 
lRetOK = TEMP-TABLE ttCust:WRITE-JSON(cTargetType, cFile, lFormatted).
```

Comment: Thanks Austin, 
Is there a way to create tables within the .p file which I  created and to call the sendEmail.p program. So that the user's will receive the emails in a tabled html format.